# Creating a hidden field in html document for debugging

Tags: html, django

I'm building a Django application with multiple pages. The  responses for few questions in these pages are stored in a Python dictionary. I need to reset this dictionary to their default values for testing purposes.

To do this, I want to create a hidden field in my html document and once I click it, a ajax function will be called to reset the dictionary..

My concern is this field should not visible to the normal user and placed such that the user does not click it unknowingly..

How can I do accomplish this?

Comment: Seems to be bad for productive environment, everyone is able to look at your source html.

Comment: you can use widgets and also djago_widget_tweaks for making tags hidden and so on. but any way users can get access to all elements in HTML codes. or you can use user.is_authenticated validation for the users who is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just for you to do the testing you can make your user either staff or superuser then use:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}

{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% request.user.is_staff%}

{% endif %}
```

Also make sure the view that does the clearing of your dictionary also checks for staff or superuser